# MySQL stored procedure causes error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Can someone kindly tell me where I'm wrong ?

This procedure returns an error near

```
@recuperato = @recuperato - saldofattura;
```

I mistake to update the variable `@recuperato`?

Thanks to all

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fatture_lettere_retail//

CREATE PROCEDURE fatture_lettere_retail (idcontratto INT(11)) 
BEGIN

DECLARE finito INT default 0;
DECLARE idfattura INT default 0;
DECLARE saldofattura DECIMAL(10,2);

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT idfattura,saldofattura FROM fatture_lettere_isa;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000'
                SET finito = 1;

SET @recuperato=(SELECT SUM(valorea)-SUM(valorer) FROM ImportiContratto WHERE idcontratto=idcontratto AND idimporto=1);


 ciclo: LOOP
            SET finito = 0;
            FETCH cur1 INTO idfattura,saldofattura;

            IF  finito THEN
                LEAVE ciclo;
            END IF; 

           IF (@recuperato-saldofattura>=0) THEN
              @recuperato = @recuperato-saldofattura;                  
              DELETE FROM fatture_lettere_isa WHERE idfattura=idfattura;  
           ELSE 
              UPDATE fatture_lettere_isa SET saldofattura=saldofattura-@recuperato;
              LEAVE ciclo;
          END IF;


    END LOOP ciclo;

    CLOSE cur1;

END; //

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error message with us? But I think you miss the SET keyword from the beginning of the @recuperato = @recuperato-saldofattura; line.

Comment: Hi, this is error message:   "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@recuperato = @recuperato-saldofattura;                  
              DELETE F' at line 25
" thanks

Comment: Then try to add the keyword SET at the beginning of that row: SET @recuperato = @recuperato-saldofattura;

Comment: THANKS SHADOW, with SET it's ok!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the SET keyword at the beginning of the row in question:

```
SET @recuperato = @recuperato-saldofattura;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write SET keyword to assign value to variable "@recuperato" as follow:

SET @recuperato = @recuperato-saldofattura;